# Prove that $\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) = x$ has infinitely many solutions in (0, 1)

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to show that $\sin\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right) = x$ has an infinite number of solutions in $(0,1)$.

I'm trying to use the Intermediate Value Theorem but with no luck.

Comment: Note this is the same equation as $\sin(y)=\frac1y$ for $y\in]1,\infty[$ and $\frac1y$ converges to $0$ as $y\to\infty$.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch this is imo the cleanest approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I'm trying to use the Intermediate Value Theorem but with no luck."

Use it an infinity number of times.

> It should be intuitively obvious that on the interval $[2k \pi, 2k\pi + \frac \pi 2]$ that $\sin x$ takes on all values from $0$ to $1$.  So on the interval $[ \frac 1{2k\pi + \frac 12 \pi},  \frac 1{2k\pi}]$ the function $\sin \frac 1x$ takes one all values from $0$ to $1$ which includes all the values between $ \frac 1{2k\pi + \frac 12 \pi}$ and $  \frac 1{2k\pi}$.   So there must be a value where they coincide.

Formally the trick to finding a *fixed* point where continuous $f(x) = x$ is to set $G(x) = f(x) -x$ and find so $x_{low}$ where $f(x_{low}) > x_low$ so $G(x_{low}) = f(x_{low}) - x= a_{high} > 0$ and some $x_{high}$ where $f(x_{high}) < x_{high}$ so $G(x_{high}) =f(x_{high})-x_{high}=a_{low} < 0$.  So by IVT, because $G(x)$ is the difference of two continuous functions and is continuous, and because $a_{low} < 0 < a_{high}$; There is a $c$ between $x_{low}$ and $x_{high}$ whever $G(c) =f(c) -c = 0$.  So $f(c) = c$.

Can we finish?:

> $\sin \frac 1x$ is continuous on $(0,1)$ so $G(x) =\sin \frac 1x-x$ on $(0,1)$.
>
> And for in $k\in \mathbb N; k\ge 1$ we have $0 < \frac  1{2k\pi + \frac 12\pi} < \frac 1{2k\pi} < 1$.  $G(\frac  1{2k\pi + \frac 12\pi}) = 1-\frac  1{2k\pi + \frac 12\pi} > 0$.  And $G(\frac 1{2k\pi})= 0 - \frac 1{2k\pi} < 0$ so  there is a $c_k \in [\frac  1{2k\pi + \frac 12\pi},\frac 1{2k\pi}]$ where $G(c_k) = \sin \frac 1c_k - c_k=0$ and  $\sin \frac 1{c_k} = c_k$.

> And as $[\frac  1{2k\pi + \frac 12\pi},\frac 1{2k\pi}]$ is disjoint from $[\frac  1{2j\pi + \frac 12\pi},\frac 1{2j\pi}]$ if $k \ne j$ then $c_k\in [\frac  1{2k\pi + \frac 12\pi},\frac 1{2k\pi}]$ while $c_j\in [\frac  1{2j\pi + \frac 12\pi},\frac 1{2j\pi}] $ mean that $c_k \ne c_j$ and there are in infinite number of these $c_k$s.

That's it.

Comment: A little overcomplicated, but gets the job done. Nice answer.

Answer (score 7):

I believe you meant to write $\sin \dfrac 1x$.

The function $f(x) = \sin \dfrac 1x$ oscillates between $1$ and $-1$ infinitely many times in the interval $(0,1)$.  Thus the function $g(x) = \sin \dfrac 1x - x$ oscillates between positive and negative values infinitely many times in that interval.

In between any two points $a$ and $b$ with $g(a) > 0$ and $g(b) < 0$ there will be a point $x$ with $g(x) = 0$, so there are infinitely many such $x$.

Comment: Wouldn't it be much simpler to replace every $x$ in $(0,1)$ with a $t$, such that $tx=1$?

Comment: "Wouldn't it be much simpler to replace every x in (0,1) with a t, such that tx=1?"  FWIW, um... no.  I don't think so.  I understood Umberto P's comments immediately but yours, although I can work it through, is not as straightforward or simple.  But... everyone's mileage varies.

Answer (score 2):

This graph of the two functions may help:

[image]

Comment: Not really. He wants a proof, not a picture.

Comment: I said "help."  Seeing how the number of cycles increases indefinitely as $x \to 0$ clearly helps.  It shows where to find the interesting cases.  It also shows that this is the "same" problem as finding the number of solutions to $\sin (1/x) = 1$ in the same domain.  The "solution" that got eight upvotes provides nothing beyond my figure, in my opinion.

Comment: I agree, but I don't think either are worth very much. In my humble opinion the only real proofs in this thread are mine and @fleablood 's.

Answer (score 1):

Make change of variable $t=1/x$. Then we want to prove $\sin(t)=1/t$ has infinitely many solutions in the range $[0,\infty)$. For $t\geq 1, 1/t \in (0,1]$. And, $\sin$ is continuous in the interval $(\pi/2, 3\pi/2)$ and takes a value of $1$ at $\pi/2$ and $-1$ at $3\pi/2$ therefore by IVT it takes all values between $-1$ and $1$ in the interval. Since $1/t \in (0,1] ~ \forall t \in (\pi/2, 3\pi/2)$ and $(0,1] \subset [-1,1]$ then $\sin(t)=1/t$ has at least one solution in this range. Since $\sin$ is periodic and $1/t$ is always in $(0,1]$ for $t\geq 1$, this argument can be repeated infinitely many times. So $\sin(t)=1/t$ has infinitely many solutions in $[1,\infty)$ thus $\sin(1/x)=x$ has infinitely many solutions in $(0,1)$.